# docker is not running for window 11 (laravel 9 project)

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I am using Docker on Ubuntu to run a Lavarel project, with sail docker. When I run the command `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` in the command line it shows the error **Docker is not running**, however, it seems to work when I run it via docker desktop.

Via cmd:

[image: cmd]

Via docker desktop:

[image: desktop]

How can I make it work via command line as well?